# What visa my Filipina wife need to travel with me to London ? (I'm Israeli and don't require a visa)

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, filipino-citizens

I have a Filipina wife, here in Israel. As an Israeli I don't require any special visa to go to London and I can get a permit as soon as I land.

What kind of visa will my wife need? Will she need to do a regular visa there? Or I will be able to say we travel together, show proof of merriage, and she will be able to enter at the landing in London?

Comment: ‘...I can get a permit as soon as I land’ As an Israeli you can visit the U.K. visa-free for Tourism/visiting family & friends for up to 6 months.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a tourist visit, she needs a Standard Visitor visa, which she gets at the local UK visa application centre.

Being married to an Israeli makes no difference.